# Regexp lookahead and lookbehind and match between certain characters

Tags: php, regex, match

Currently I have this regexp to detect strings between double curly brackets and it work's wonderfully.

```
$str = "{{test}} and {{test2}}";
preg_match_all('/(?<={{)[^}]*(?=}})/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);

Returns:
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => test
        [1] => test2
    )

)
```

Now I need to expand it to only match stuff between ]] and [[

```
$str = "{{dont match}}]]{{test}} and {{test2}}[[{{dont match}}";
```

I've been trying to modify the regex but the lookahead and lookbehind is making it too difficult for me. How can I get it to match stuff inside ]] and [[ only?

Also I would like to match the whole string between ]] and [[ and then I would like to match each individual string between {{ }} inside it.

For example:

```
$str = "{{dont match}}]]{{test}} and {{test2}}[[{{dont match}}";

Would return:
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => {{test}} and {{test2}}
        [1] => test
        [2] => test2
    )

)
```

Comment: Please post the modified regex you used with

Comment: Well it didn't work, I tried adding \\]\\] and \\[\\[ around the (?<={{)[^}]*(?=}}) etc. but the lookahead and lookbehind doesn't work like that.

Comment: Take a step back. Can't you first match against `]]....[[` (with the regex you posted slightly modified) and then do the posted regex on the result of the first one?

Comment: @unska is your input always be in the above format?

Comment: I could and this is how it's working now but I would love to have them in the same regex. I'm afraid two regexes will eventually create more stress compared to one.

Comment: Avinash, as far as the ]] {{ }} [[ goes, yes. Naturally the strings inside them changes.

Comment: So in other words, you want to avoid content enclosed between `[[` and `]]`, isn't it?

Comment: [[for item in products]]Name: {{name}}, model: {{model}}[[/for]]. I only want to match the stuff inside ]] and [[. The "Name: {{name}}, model: {{model}}" part.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/oC3qA3/4

Comment: Avinash, this correctly matches the whole string inside the ]] [[. Is it possible to have the regex match the whole string and the individual strings inside {{ }}? As stated on my example in the original question (search for "Would return:")

Comment: Actually, I think I'm going to go with your solution and then create another regexp after it that matches the curly bracket strings. Could you post your solution as an answer so I can pick it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Piggyback using `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$str = "{{dont match}}]]{{test}} and {{test2}}[[{{dont match}}";
$arr = array();
preg_replace_callback('/\]\](.*?)\[\[/', function($m) use (&$arr) {
            preg_match_all('/(?<={{)[^}]*(?=}})/', $m[1], $arr); return true; }, $str);
print_r($arr[0]);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => test
    [1] => test2
)
```